# How to fix a header in a WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a website for a friend of mine in a WordPress. I stumbled on a problem, can't fix a header on website. The title of a company pops up really big when loading a page, it return to normal as soon as you scroll down. I'm using pre-made theme for a site. [Here is a photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAWkZ.jpg) of what it looks like.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7g8jg.jpg) is how it should look like.

Comment: You need to show us some code, like the header one. It's probably a CSS problem so this is not the correct category

Comment: Please provide code. We can't possibly help you if you don't explain to us what you already tried.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping stackoverflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because the height of the image is being set when the class .fixed is present. This class is only added when you scroll.

The solution would be to add this style:

```
.top-bar .name h1 a img {
    max-height: 60px;
}
```

This will set the image to be 60px in height and will not depend on the .fixed class.

I also suggest for future questions you provide a link to the site.